# delete the character or string before nth delimiter '|'

Tags: oracle

I have a **LOG_TAB** table where column **COLLEC_VAL** values are `Abcd@123|Mnbv@1234|Poiu@1234|Asdf@1234|.......` in oracle. These values are not fixed. I want to keep only latest 4 string or character in the column and rest of the values will be deleted, that is **Abcd@1234** will be deleted checking with delimiter(|).

After deleting first one, below values will be available:
`Mnbv@1234|Poiu@1234|Asdf@1234|.......`

how it will check that already 4 or grater than 3 delimiter exist and delete the first one? Please help.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Say you have one record with `'aa|bb|cc'`, one with `'aa|bb|cc|dd'` and one with `'aa|bb|cc|dd|ee'`. Should the results, respectively, be `'aa|bb|cc'`, `'aa|bb|cc|dd'`, and `'bb|cc|dd|ee'`  ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: The `....` implies there are more values; your description seems a little contradictory, it isn't clear if you only want to remove the very first one if there are more than 3 three delimiters, however many there are; or more than one. Please edit your question to add more examples and expected results to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update log_tab set collec_val = substr(collec_val, instr(collec_val, '|', -1, 4)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help for all your columns try this on a table,it show you sample emp table's data:

```
select SUBSTR(listagg(ename,'|') within group (order by ename),instr(listagg(ename,'|') within group (order by ename),'|',-1,4)+1) employee_name from emp;
```